# How to get the onfocus event to fire for checkbox in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, firefox, web-applications

In IE i am using an onfocusin event and everything works as expected for the checkbox however onfocusin only works with IE and not other browsers. Also the onfocus doesn't work for checkbox's either no matter which browser your in. Is there something i'm missing here? Sample below ( check box only fires in ie) I am using asp.net 4.0

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
     <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function CheckOnFocus() {
             alert('got focus');
         }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onfocus="CheckOnFocus(this);"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onfocusin="CheckOnFocus(this);" />
     </div>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Opera, Google Chrome and Safari, use the DOMFocusIn event instead of the onfocusin event.

In Firefox, if you need to detect whether a child of an element gets the focus, use a capturing listener for the onfocus event.

To detect when an element loses focus, use the onblur, onfocusout and DOMFocusOut events.

```
 function Init () {
        var form = document.getElementById ("myForm");
        if ("onfocusin" in form) {  // Internet Explorer
                // the attachEvent method can also be used in IE9,
                // but we want to use the cross-browser addEventListener method if possible
            if (form.addEventListener) {    // IE from version 9
                form.addEventListener ("focusin", OnFocusInForm, false);
                form.addEventListener ("focusout", OnFocusOutForm, false);
            }
            else {
                if (form.attachEvent) {     // IE before version 9
                    form.attachEvent ("onfocusin", OnFocusInForm);
                    form.attachEvent ("onfocusout", OnFocusOutForm);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (form.addEventListener) {    // Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari
                    // since Firefox does not support the DOMFocusIn/Out events
                    // and we do not want browser detection
                    // the focus and blur events are used in all browsers excluding IE
                    // capturing listeners, because focus and blur events do not bubble up
                form.addEventListener ("focus", OnFocusInForm, true);
                form.addEventListener ("blur", OnFocusOutForm, true);
            }
        }
    }

    function OnFocusInForm (event) {
        var target = event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement;
        if (target) {
            target.style.color = "red";
        }
    }
    function OnFocusOutForm (event) {
        var target = event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement;
        if (target) {
            target.style.color = "";
        }
    }

</script>

<body onload="Init ()">
   <form id="myForm">
      User name: <input type="text" value="my name"/><br />
       E-mail: <input type="text" value="myname@mydomain.com"/>
    </form>
 </body>
```

**UPDATED**
another way you can do it like this for individual control

```
     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
       document.querySelector('#checkboxname').addEventListener('focus', focusHandler);
    });

    function focusHandler(){
     }


    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxname" name="checkboxname"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. How would this work for a checkbox? The user may tab into the checkbox instead of click it. I cant seem to get that to work with your provided function.

Comment: it will work for all the elements in the form, and event.target will give you the control name.. and then you can play with event.target to perform your activity

Comment: With more extensive testing with CheckBox i found this is working in Firefox and IE but not with Chrome and Safari.

Comment: call the init method to addeventlistener onload of body

Comment: I have <body onload="Init();"> as you said. Everything fires off ok in all the browsers except for checkbox in Chrome and Safari

Comment: i just found that its a bug in webkit, details [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22261)